# Cargar Sass en React con @use

Tags: reactjs, sass

tengo un problema al utilizar @use de Sass en React. Ya instalé node-sass e importe el index.scss en el App.jsx

Estoy usando el @use en Sass para dividir el código en varios archivos, pero no reconoce la funcionalidad.

Al intentar colocar la funcionalidad, me dice:

> SassError: Undefined variable: "$color".
> on line 13 of src/styles/main/index.scss
>
> > background-color: $color;
> > --^

O lo que es lo mismo, que la variable en el archivo no existe, cuando SI la declare en el archivo Sass ´utils.scss´

```css
//Archivo SASS con node-sass

//'utils.scss'
$color: #818;

//index.scss
@use 'utils' as *;

*{
background-color: $color;
}


//No lee lo escrito en el 'utils.scss'
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

//Importar SCSS 
import './styles/main/index.scss';
```

Comment: A mi me pasaba algo parecido hace un tiempo y era porque usaba un plugin para compilar al guardar y si hacia un cambio en uno después tenía que compilar también el otro para que reconozca los cambios.

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que estás realizando la compilación de los scss, si es asi y estas estás seguro que realizas bien la compilación de los archivos sass, mi recomendación seria que pruebes con otro paquete de npm y hagas pruebas.

Recomiendo que pruebes:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass

Este paquete es el que recomienda la documentación oficial de sass.